# My shop is Magento 1.3. What is the problem when update to 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

I am from Brazil and the problem is following:

The site [Termall Ice Machine](http://www.termall.com.br) is using Magento version 1.3. But I would like to make a site better.

I am afraid to break up some function of the site, because any people said to me that update can break up functions.

Is it true? What kind of technical problem can happen? I insert mysite here to anybody see where is possible to break up the site and mark.

Comment: You need to perform a double upgrade, better you perfom a migration (new install and import the data) otherwise you are going to experience all sorts of problems.

Comment: Agree on that. If you go the upgrade route, must have an intermediate upgrade to 1.4.2.0 as there were major database changes that will cause 1.3.x.x to 1.5.x.x and above to choke mightily. NO LIVE SERVER upgrades on this one without thorough testing in a dev environment either way.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps that we normally take with an upgrade. Note you **CAN** upgrade directly from 1.3 to 1.9. We have done this. You don't have to make incremental steps between versions. (Unless you are upgrading Enterprise to 1.13)

**NEVER UPGRADE A LIVE SITE, ALWAYS MAKE A BACKUP FIRST**

You will want to take a clean version of Magento, without any of your modules or theme items and do a test upgrade of your site. This will tell you if your site will upgrade properly.

Then go through the following procedure:

**CORE:**

Identify and list modules to go to upgraded version
Diff Core of original version to clean core of same version
If you have a local/Mage folder you will need to check if the code is compatible with the version you are upgrading to.

Dump old database and restore in new database
mysqldump -u user -p ‘password’ -h host olddatabase > yourdump.sql
mysql -u user -p ‘password’ -h host newdatabase < yourdump.sql

**THEME:**

You will not be able to simply migrate your theme from this version to the the current as the folder structure has changed.

**External items** (Like ERP)

Identify external components that need to function with new version, review on Magento integration options (i.e. does it make sense to make the external app a Magento app or leave it as an external app)

Check that all your Magento indexes are up to date

It always helps to use source control like GIT

The procedure is more time consuming but it will ensure you have a stable upgraded site when you are finished.

Answer (score 0):

I Paulo your website is working on a very old version of Magento after that there are huge changes inside the Magento core code. So basis on that there are few things where the complexity exist:-

1. First you need to take back up of your website like full code and database because your site can be break between this process and which will take time to resolve those issue.
2. Then you need to check custom extension which you are using into your current website. List down one by one and check if those extension also have there upgraded version which we can use with your updated website. Because old version will not support with upgraded version of Magento.
3. If you have any customisation with in core code of magento then those changes will be lost after the upgradation, so note down first if there is. So it will easy to make that same functionality after upgradation.
4. Then you can upgrade your Magento website from 1.3 to 1.4.2 firstly then upgrade from 1.4.2 to latest version.

I hope , you got the your answer.